# A question related to a complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

Let $\Delta$ be the unit disc centered at $0$ in the complex plane and consider an analytic function $g:\Delta \to \Delta $ such that $g(0)=0$. I have proved the following claim (using *Schwarz Lemma*).

> For all $z\in \Delta,$ we have $|g(z)+g(-z)|\leq 2|z|^2.$

I would like to show that

> If $|g(a)+g(-a)|= 2|a|^2$, for some $0<|a|<1$, then there is a constant $c$ with $|c|=1$ such that $g(z)=cz^2$, for all $z\in \Delta$.

**My Attempt:** Let $h(z)=\frac{g(z)+g(-z)}{2}$. I've managed to show that $h$ has the form $h(z)=k(z^2)$, for some function $k$. Since $h(z)\leq 1$, for all $z\in\Delta$ and $h(0)=0$, it follows by *Schwarz Lemma* that there exists a constant $c$ with $|c|=1$ such that $|k(z^2)|=cz^2$, so it follows that $\frac{g(z)+g(-z)}{2}=cz^2\Longrightarrow g(z)+g(-z)=2cz^2.$

**My Question:** How do I proceed from here to show that $g(z)=cz^2$?

Any help/hint will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $g(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ the equality $g(z)+g(-z)=2cz^2$ implies $a_2=c$ and then Parseval inequality $\sum |a_k|^2 \le 1$ gives $a_n=0$ for all $n \ne 2$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the response. If you don't mind, what is the statement for Parseval's inequality?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^1|g(re^{it})|^2dt=\sum |a_k|^2r^{2n}$ so since $|g| \le 1$ we get $\sum |a_k|^2r^{2n} \le 1$ and letting $r \to 1$ gives us $\sum |a_k|^2 \le 1$ which is Parseval inequality (more generally if $|f| \le M$ on the unit disc we get an $M^2$ bound for $\sum |a_k|^2$)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!